Unreachable subnet of MikroTik router via wireguard on VPS
My goal is to set up a wireguard connection from my home router to a VPS and connect from the outside through this connection to my different home networks (here, only one network is depicted).
The router I'm using is a MikroTik. This one is connecting to the VPS via these rules/configuration:
/interface/wireguard/export
/interface wireguard
add listen-port=36857 mtu=1420 name=wg-xxx-it
add disabled=yes listen-port=13231 mtu=1420 name=wireguard
/interface wireguard peers
add allowed-address=0.0.0.0/0 client-address=192.168.7.1/24 endpoint-address=wg.xxx-it.de endpoint-port=51820 interface=wg-xxx-it name=peer-wg-xxx-it persistent-keepalive=30m preshared-key="xxxx" public-key=\
    "xxxx"

/ip address
add address=192.168.0.1/24 comment="xxx-net" interface="bridge" network=192.168.0.0
add address=192.168.7.1/24 comment=VPN interface=wg-xxx-it network=192.168.7.0

The corresponding configuration for the (mobile) client looks like this:
[Interface]
PrivateKey = xxx
Address = 192.168.7.10/24
DNS = 192.168.7.1

[Peer]
PublicKey = xxx
PresharedKey = xxx
AllowedIPs = 192.168.7.0/24, 192.168.0.0/24
PersistentKeepalive = 0
Endpoint = wg.xxx-it.de:51820

When the router and my client are connected to the VPS via Wireguard, they can see each other (ping, traceroute). That's great. Router gets the IP 192.168.7.1/24, client 192.168.7.10/24 as I want them to be.
However, I'm struggling now at connecting from my client to other parts of the home network. As for the wireguard server, I'm using wg-easy with the following env-variables in docker-compose configuration:
environment:
  - WG_ALLOWED_IPS=192.168.7.0/24, 192.168.0.0/24
  - WG_DEFAULT_ADDRESS=192.168.7.x
  - WG_DEFAULT_DNS=192.168.7.1
  - WG_POST_UP=ip route add 192.168.0.0/24 via 192.168.7.1
  - WG_POST_DOWN=ip route rm 192.168.0.0/24 via 192.168.7.1

When I do a traceroute from my client to some device on the home network, I end up in endless hops (unreachable).
It looks to me like the route on the VPS is not working correctly, however, the route is there:
xxx:/app# route
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
default         docker-xx-xxxxx 0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 eth0
10.8.0.0        *               255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 wg0
172.28.0.0      *               255.255.0.0     U     0      0        0 eth0
192.168.0.0     192.168.7.1     255.255.255.0   UG    0      0        0 wg0
192.168.7.1     *               255.255.255.255 UH    0      0        0 wg0
192.168.7.10    *               255.255.255.255 UH    0      0        0 wg0

Is there some configuration missing on router or on VPS?

What do you see in a packet capture when you connect from the client to some PC? For example, on the Mikrotik, does /tool/sniffer/quick for a specific IP address show packets arriving through the WG interface, and the same packets being forwarded out through the LAN bridge interface?

I used the packet sniffer and filtered for the src-ip of the client (and in a second run on the whole subnet 192.168.7.0). Packet for destination 192.168.7.1 arrive, no indication of any packets when I try to connect to a subnet. So it seems to me it's the routing of the client or VPS

How about tcpdump -n -i wg0 on the VPS in that case? (See https://man.archlinux.org/man/pcap-filter.7 for filter syntax). I assume you meant no packets when connecting to addresses in the 192.168.0.x subnet?

IP 192.168.7.10 > 192.168.0.83: ICMP echo request, id 6995, seq 64071, length 24
IP 10.8.0.1 > 192.168.7.10: ICMP host 192.168.0.83 unreachable, length 52

Does the VPS wg0 interface's "peer" section (for your Mikrotik) have 192.168.0.0/24 in its AllowedIPs? [WireGuard doesn't support via routes, for the same reason it cannot be bridged.]

Seems reasonable. Currently 0.0.0.0/0 is in the allowed IPs for the MikroTik peer. I've added 192.168.0.0/24 (and also tried it without 0.0.0.0/0), but with same unreachable message as above.

Have you checked your firewall settings yet?
Add a rule like this for example and try to reach other devices on your network.
Anywhere on eth0 ALLOW FWD   your_wireguard_VLan on wg0

I don't think I understand this correctly. Do you mean in routeros? The home network is on the bridge as is the wireguard interface.

@eraelpeha: Is it really? WireGuard interfaces cannot be part of a bridge (they're not Ethernet-like interfaces), and your configuration very strongly implies that the Mikrotik's wg0 indeed isn't bridged (because it has its own IP subnet and everything)

@grawity: Thanks for the hint. It currently is part of the bridge via an interface list, that is part of the bridge. To avoid misunderstanding: wg0 is the interface on the VPS, the interface on MikroTik is called wg-xxx-it.

@eraelpeha: Even if it's added to an interface list that's a bridge member, the interface itself cannot become a bridge member – it literally doesn't carry the Ethernet headers that bridging would operate on – so the entry is just ignored.

@grawity: Good point. So as suggested I've added a firewall rules: add action=accept chain=forward dst-address=192.168.0.0/24 log=yes src-address=192.168.7.0/24
However, the behaviour is the same.
